# How to use zustand for user auth global state in next.js 13.4.9

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, zustand

I have the following code in my Next.js 13.4.9 app (using the app router) and I'm not sure how to effectively use zustand to manage global auth state.

zustand store:

```
// /src/store/AuthStore.ts

import { create } from 'zustand';
import { persist } from 'zustand/middleware';

type User = {
    token: string | null;
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
};
  
type AuthActions = {
    login: (token: string) => void;
    logout: () => void;
};

const useAuthStore = create<User & AuthActions>()(
    persist((set, get) => ({
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        login: token => set({ token, isAuthenticated: true }),
        logout: () => set({ token: null, isAuthenticated: false })
      }),
      { name: 'auth', getStorage: () => localStorage }
    )
);

export default useAuthStore;
```

Register page:

```
// /app/register/page.tsx

"use client";

import { FormEvent, FormEventHandler, useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { DuplicateUserError } from '@/lib/exceptions/DuplicateUserError';
import useAuthStore from '@/store/AuthStore';
import Error from "@/app/error";
import styles from "./page.module.scss";

const Register: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error | null>(null);
  const login = useAuthStore(state => state.login);

  const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler = async (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData: FormData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);
    const formValues: { [k: string]: FormDataEntryValue } =
        Object.fromEntries(formData);

    const { username, email, password } = formValues;

    try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/register", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, email, password }),
        });

        if (!(res.status === 201)) {
          setError(new DuplicateUserError());
        } else {
          // login user
        }

    } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err);
    }
  };

  if (error) {
    return (
      <Error 
        error={error} 
        reset={() => setError(null)} 
      />);
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.login}>
        <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Link href="/login" className={styles.register}>
            switch to login
          </Link>
          <input
            className={styles.input}
            placeholder="username"
            type="text"
            name="username"
            autoComplete="off"
            required
          />
          <input
            className={styles.input}
            placeholder="email"
            type="email"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="off"
            required
          />
          <input
            className={styles.input}
            placeholder="password"
            type="password"
            name="password"
            required
          />
          <button className={styles.button}>Register</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

What I want to do is update my global state when a new user registers on the site. Specifically, when the registration completes successfully, I want the user to be logged in (authenticated) on the site. Does anyone know how to complete the code in the Register component here?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `token` by calling the `login()` function as shown below.

```
const Register: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error | null>(null);
  const login = useAuthStore(state => state.login);

  const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler = async (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData: FormData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);
    const formValues: { [k: string]: FormDataEntryValue } =
        Object.fromEntries(formData);

    const { username, email, password } = formValues;

    try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/register", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, email, password }),
        });

        if (!(res.status === 201)) {
          setError(new DuplicateUserError());
        } else {
           login('token-here'); //set state
        }

    } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err);
    }
  };
  //... existing code
};

export default Register;
```

The `token` and `isAuthenticated` is now updated globally, and can be accessed like so:

```
const isAuthenticated = useAuthStore((s) => s.isAuthenticated);
```

#### Edit

Keep in mind that this will only set the token, not authenticate the user. You need to validate the token too.

You can solve this by adding an `useEffect` in your App, and have it validate the token from localstorage on every refresh. If the token is valid, call the `login()` function and set the user as `isAuthenticated`.

Example:

App.tsx:

```
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    useCurrentUser();
  }, []);
  return <></>;
}
```

```
export async function useCurrentUser() {
   const login = useAuthStore((state) => state.login);
   const data = await fetch('url'); //auth endpoint that validates the token
   if (data) {
      login('token-here');
   }
}
```